# Get file owner in Windows using PHP

Tags: php

Provide a path to file, and get its owner username on Windows?

Of course, `fileowner` is useless here.

Any PECL extensions that can help?

Edit: Alternative that will also work:

Read the summary data from a .DOC file, to retrieve the Author.

Edit 2: Found a solution using `COM("word.application")`. Any others?

Comment: Please post the solution you found as an answer to this question so that others may benefit. You don't have to mark it as solved, to encourage others to post.

Answer (score 1):

You could try parsing a System call like System("icacls $file", $return_value) though that only works on windows and is not the cleanest solution

Comment: This command doesn't return the owner of the file (though it can set it).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this (for any file of any type) by shelling out to the command line and executing a DIR /Q command on the file:

```
$output = shell_exec('dir ' . $filepath . '/Q');

$output = explode(' ', $output);

foreach($output as $entry) {
    if(strtoupper($entry) == '{DOMAIN}\\' . strtoupper($loggedInUser)) {
        $owner = str_replace('{DOMAIN}\\', '', $entry);
    }
}
```

This functions properly only a Windows system while the native PHP function `fileOwner` functions properly only on a linux system.

Where I work, we have a PHP extension that somehow extracts this information with a single function call but I have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just find solution for this problem. Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458656/2592415

```
$path = 'D:\Some File\Some Another File\document.doc'; // File or dir path
$su = new COM("ADsSecurityUtility"); // Call interface
$securityInfo = $su->GetSecurityDescriptor($path, 1, 1); // Call method
echo $securityInfo->owner; // Get file owner
```