# Reading file and directory owner using PHP on the Windows

Tags: php, windows, shell, file-ownership

I have an intranet project based on the PHP and xampp server on the Windows. That intranet project have database with table where I store scanned disc drive informations of files and folders. I using simple windows command `dir "$directory_path" /Q /T:C` to get informations.

After that I use regex to match and parse that info to separate date, time, permission and dir name like on this example:

[EXAMPLE REGEX FOR DIRECTORY PARSING](https://regex101.com/r/Odw9sx/1)

It's similar like this example: [Get file owner in Windows using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390677/get-file-owner-in-windows-using-php)

This working fine but sometimes file owner names are realy long and was stripped by command line. In that case I can't read full name and functionality is broken.

Now I searching for another solution.

My PHP have instaled also `php_com_dotnet.dll` extension and I using `COM()` class in some part of code.

My main question is:

-Can I use `COM()` class to get real file informations and avoid shell commands for the file search and listings and how?

-Is there some another extension, shell command or something 3rd what I can use to get file/folder owners?

NOTE: I need this only for the reading and indexing in the database, don't need to change permissions or ownership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find simple solution for this using PHP class [COM()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) and the documentation of the [IADsSecurityUtility::GetSecurityDescriptor method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nf-iads-iadssecurityutility-getsecuritydescriptor).

The code in PHP looks like this:

```
$path = 'D:\Some File\Some Another File\document.doc'; // File or dir path
$su = new COM("ADsSecurityUtility"); // Call interface
$securityInfo = $su->GetSecurityDescriptor($path, 1, 1); // Call method
echo $securityInfo->owner; // Get file owner
```

That's all folks.

### NOTE

> **COM functions are only available for the Windows version of PHP.**
>
> .Net support requires PHP 5 and the .Net runtime.
>
> As of PHP 5.3.15 / 5.4.5, this extension requires **php_com_dotnet.dll**
>   to be enabled inside of php.ini in order to use these functions.
>   Previous versions of PHP enabled these extensions by default.
>
> **You are responsible for installing support for the various COM objects**

Comment: It seems that if there are any multibyte characters in the pathname, it does not work properly. Does anybody know a way around it?

Comment: Yes, well, you need to convert filenames to UTF-8 to can display properly. But comparing and including files you can do only with direct path. It is a bit complicated but it's only way. Look at this repo I made for encodings: https://github.com/CreativForm/PHP-Solutions/blob/master/class.encoding.php